# Communicating with Pure Data in C

Tags: c, puredata

I'm looking for a way to be able to communicate with a Pure Data patch via C programming - I suppose this is different from writing an external in C which involves writing patches themselves. I only need to communicate and make changes in existing patches. For instance, in the patch shown in the image: [image]

I need to find a way to change the delay parameters programmatically, in the case of the three objects `delwrite~`, `*~`, and `delread~`. I wish to write a simple C program that communicates with Pure Data, loads the patch and makes the required changes. Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: is that "C-program" running within the address-space of Pd or as a separate process?

Comment: Ideally I would want to run it as a separate process rather than using an external

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are numerous ways to communicate with a running Pd instance.

The most straightforward one is to use network communication:

- `[netreceive]` allows you to receive messages from another process, using the [FUDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FUDI) protocol. The following patch listens on `UDP/9999` for incoming messages:

[image: network controlled feedback patch]

- on the C-side, just create a normal UDP-socket and send the data to `localhost:9999` (assuming your process runs on the same machine).

Alternative methods include using [libpd](http://libpd.cc), which is a library version of Pd and allows you to load Pd-patches directly in your program.